# Web Sockets in Amfphp for data synchronization for all clients

Tags: flash, apache-flex, websocket, amfphp

I am googling since many days, and trying to figure out, how to synchronize (datagrid)data among clients using push method in amfphp.

I found that sockets can do this for me. But I dont find any such example, where I can study and implement in my code.

I am using Flex, Amfphp, Mysql.

Mysql has a database with table containing employee details

Flex has a datagrid, filled with data retrieved from mysql.

Amfphp is used for remoting the data(retrieving and updating etc).

But the data among users is not in sync. The data should update in clients browser, whenever there is an change in database. It may be achieved using sockets(I think so, I have no knowledge regarding this).

I hope this question is simple to understand. 
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you might want to look at this:
http://flashmog.net/ 
I'm warning you though, what you want to do is far from trivial in PHP, as PHP does mot manage communication between threads, events, etc. You might want to use another server side language such as Java. Otherwise check out "long polling"

Comment: Sorry for late reply, but i am still in dilemma to which to use, polling or pushing. As my data in datagrid has to be in sync and should not have any delay in displaying updated data in datagrid. Thanks